# "blowtorch" in Esperanto

Tags: single-word-requests

How would you translate the word "blowtorch" in Esperanto? I was thinking of *flamigilo*, but it only has one hit in Tekstaro.

[image]

Picture from https://www.flickr.com/photos/58819758@N00/4213632566 (CC-by 2.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi sugestas `ŝalmo` (Fundamenta). La radiko jam enhavas la signifon *blovi/ŝprucigi* kaj, laŭ [la difino en PIV](https://vortaro.net/#%C5%9Dalmo_kd) tio estas:

> Duobla tubo, per kiu, kombinante brulgason, hidrogenon aŭ acetilenon,
> kun oksigeno, oni povas ŝprucigi sur difinitan k malvastan lokon tre
> varmigan flamon, ebligantan luti, veldi aŭ fandi metalojn.

Comment: FWIW, Wikipedia knows the word [_ŝalmo_](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ŝalmo) only in the sense of a music instrument. Even if I cannot weld, it looks to me that the PIV's definition of _ŝalmo_ describes a [welding blowpipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowpipe_(tool)) rather than a blowtorch. They are different tools.

Answer (score 0):

En la Vikipedia artikolo pri [portebla kuirilo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portebla_kuirilo) oni havas terminon blovtorĉo, kvankam mankas la artikolo pri la termino mem. Ambaŭ partoj de la vorto **blovtorĉo** estas fundamentaj, kaj la kunmetita vorto bazas sur la difinoj de la vortoj, vd. [blovi](https://vortaro.net/#blovi_kd) kaj [torĉo](https://vortaro.net/#tor%C4%89o_kd) en PIV, por priskribi, pri kio temas: portebla, malferma fajro, kiun oni povas "blovi", direkti ien.

Comment: Averto! Se vi guglas pri "blovtorĉo", vi certe trovas paĝon kun instrukcioj kiel ĝuste malŝraŭbi riglilojn. Tiu retejo ŝajnas esti aŭtomate tradukita.